# Using Google Places API in Kendo UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, kendo-ui, google-places-api

I was trying to use the [Google Places API (Places Autocomplete)](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) in my [Kendo UI Autocomplete](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete) in my mobile web app but I was having hard time finding tutorial on how to do this.

Right now this is what i've done..

```
        requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";

        var dsLocations = {
            serverFiltering: true,
            type: "odata",
            transport:
            {
                read: {
                    url: requestUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",

                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                    delete paramMap.$inlinecount; 
                    delete paramMap.$format; 
                    return paramMap;
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data.length;
                },

            },
        };

        $("#autocomplete-locations").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: dsLocations,
            minLength: 3,
            filter: "contains",
            dataTextField: "TextForSearch",
            dataValueField: "TextForSearch"
        });
```

Comment: I see code but I don't see a question. What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work! :) --- my problem is how to use Google Places in Kendo Autocomplete. What I've done was how I do this using custom web api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! You dont even need kendo.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform